# Casting with generics in C#

Tags: c#

Given the following snippet, how can I cast `IMessage` to type of `TMessage`?

```
public void Publish<TMessage>(IMessage message) 
{
     var t = typeof(TMessage);
     MyFunction((t)message); // how can a cast message to type of TMessage?
}
```

Comment: I am wondering why do you want to do something like this.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the type of `message` to be `TMessage` in the first place?

Comment: What is the definition of `MyFunction`?  From the code, I infer that it must be a generic method as well, or it would require a parameter of a specific type and wouldn't accept one of `TMessage`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any other cast:

```
public void Publish<TMessage>(IMessage message) {
    var t = (TMessage)message;
    MyFunction(t);
}
```

**Edit:**
If compiler says 'invalid cast', then is probably right. However, for cases when compiler is not right, you can "trick" him.

```
public void Publish<TMessage>(IMessage message) {
    var t = (TMessage)(object)message;
    MyFunction(t);
}
```

Comment: It will give runtime error if casting is not valid.

Comment: Yes. And that's good. It's better to get InvalidCastException than NullReferenceException in following code.

Comment: Is below solution not proper?

Comment: The "TMessage" must be reference type. And calling "MyFunction(null)" will result in NullReferenceException probably. However that depends on implementation of MyFunction and what the "Publish" method should do. The "MyFunction" can accept "null" argument, but the result will be probably other, than expect caller of "Publish" method. I can imagine scenarios, where it is valid, but I don't expect that behaviour as user of that class/library.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Publish<TMessage>(IMessage message) {
    var t = message as TMessage;
    MyFunction(t);
}
```

It will set t as null instead of giving runtime error.

Comment: This requires a `class` constraint on `TMessage` to compile and won't result in a compile-time error if the cast is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to cast some parameters, just use generic methods.

```
// Your code
public void Publish<TMessage>(IMessage message) 
{
     var t = typeof(TMessage);
     MyFunction((t)message); // how can a cast message to type of TMessage?
}

// Modified version
public void Publish<TMessage>(TMessage message) where TMessage : IMessage
{
     MyFunction(message);
}
```